# Screen problems - Ubuntu 14.04, Radeon HD 4850, Gallium drivers and 50 inch TV

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, hdmi

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04, Radeon HD 4850, using Gallium drivers and a 50" Panasonic TV for display attached to graphic cards HDMI output, but I can not get the desktop 100% inside the display view.  Some parts of the desktop is outside the screen, like the output from the graphic card is bigger than what fits inside the tv...LOL (english is not my native language, so please accept my apology for not beeing able to describe this better).

Take a look at this picture: http://i58.tinypic.com/2gtbz9w.jpg

I have tried every setting I can think of on my TV, setting the source to everything from PC to HDMI1/HDMI2 etc, but no change.  I have also tried to change the TV's aspect ratio (Auto, 16:9,14:9,4:3,Zoom1,Zoom2,Zoom3) etc, but nothing helps.

Anyone able to help me solve this challenge?  Or do I simply need to buy a new graphic card?

I can add that Ubuntu sees the TV as 32" Panasonic, even if it is 50".  Don't know if this helps narrowing down the problem/solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out - I disabled overscan in my TV setup menu.

Comment: Note to reviewers: this is the OP's answer.